# Use intent in a class that does not extends Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am facing problem in using Intent in a class that does not extends Activity Class.

If I use intent in my MainActivity then it is working perfectly fine. Following is code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public void goToRegistrationPage(View view){
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);       
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

But if same Intent code if i use following way then it gives error.

```
public class Common {
    public static void moveToAnotherActivity(){
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(this,RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Problems in Common Class

- It is giving error in this.
- It is giving error in startActivity method.
- if i convert this to context it still gives error might be i am not giving context in right way

Comment: You may dont know what is use of `this` and where to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent   =   new Intent(this,RegistrationActivity.class);
```

this means you can only use from an **Activity** class
or else you should pass the `ApplicationContext` to the intent class like

```
public class Common {

    public static void moveToAnotherActivity(RegistrationActivity obj){
        obj.finish();
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(obj,RegistrationActivity.class);
        obj.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and use from your activity `Common.moveToAnotherActivity(this)`

Comment: Now it gives error "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Common"

Comment: @employeegts Use `c.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I am trying to use finish method but it gives error. I tried with c.finish() and intent.finish but both way it gives error. can you please tell me how to call finish method here?

Comment: Use `((Activity) c).finish();`

Comment: @Pratik it does not work. Giving error "Activity can not be resolved to type"

Comment: @employeegts Before accepting you have to think once. Have u checked this answer is perfect.

Comment: @Pratik Sorry, if it is not according to you actually i was looking to accpet 2 answers but unfortunately there is only one answer to accept. You also helped me a lot in this specific question so please tell me if there is any alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor that you're using:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

(defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))) requires a `Context` object and a class so all you have to do is change `moveToAnotherActivity()` to `moveToAnotherActivity(Context context)` and create the intent using the context:

```
new Intent(context, RegistrationActivity.class);
```

Any activity, application or service could be a valid context so all you have to do is figure out which one is more appropriate and use it.

Answer (score 1):

In first activity pass a weak reference to the class that doesn't extend activity.

```
WeakReference<Context> mContext =new WeakReference<Context>(getApplicationContext());


public class Common {
Context ctx;
public Common( WeakReference<Context> ctx){
this.ctx=ctx.get();
}

    public static void moveToAnotherActivity(){
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(this,RegistrationActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to pass `context` or `activity` reference to the method.

Like

```
public class Common {
    public static void moveToAnotherActivity(Activity _activity){
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(_activity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //You can use finish here like
        _activity.finish();
    }
}
```

If you want to finish here that activity then pass Activity Reference otherwise `finish` activity from where you are calling this method.

You have to call from `MainActivity` like:

```
Comman.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this);
```

**Edited:** As per @Kumara Rajan's Solution you may get error like:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

You can solve by adding this `intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );`

Any Question, Feel free to Ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the context of the activity in Intent.

If you are class is not extends Activity, it will not hold a context, hence it will not work.

To solve this issue you can use the ***application context*** and use below flag to start in separate task.

```
intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
```

If you are starting an activity form outside an activity and doesn't add above flag, you will get below exception:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:629)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:231)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:326)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
```

Comment: Half Answer is Unrelated to Question. By the way `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is default flag.

Answer (score 0):

first, you create a `Context` in your class:

```
public class MyClass extends Thread {
    Context mContext;
    public MyClass(Context context){

        this.mContext = context;
}
```

then you call your Activity like this:

```
public void callActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

*DO NOT FORGET* to add the flag to you intent, if you do, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Use intent in your non activity class like this and pass the context of your activity to this class :-

```
Intent intent   =   new Intent(context,RegistrationActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It should be `yourclassname.this` Like `new Intent(yourclassname.this,RegistrationActivity.class);`